# Can only access .net framework when running as administrator

Tags: .net-framework

I have a problem with my .net framework. I can only run applications using the .net framework as an administrator, like Visual Studio.

How can I solve this problem, so it is possible to run a program in normal state, using .net?

Using win 7, 64 bit

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: Just "Visual Studio has encountered a problem, and needs to close."
My Messenger program opens, but looks like this (http://i234.photobucket.com/albums/ee48/mekugi/wml.jpg)